# How to load images from server in PDF file?

Tags: image, pdf, server, external

I have to create PDF file with images in external location. I have 137 jpg files and each file is one page, so 1.jpg is 1st page, 2.jpg is 2nd page etc. I need to load this images from my server and if I edit any image, this change will be avaiable in this PDF file because images are loaded from my server. I searched for any solution for that but I couldn't find any correct answer. There is any way to do that?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand! You are sitting at a Windows or Linux box? Your server is Windows or Linux? Your images are local or on your server? Your PDF must be created locally or on your server? What protocols does your server support - HTTP, FTP, SSH? What language do you expect to use?

Comment: Ugh. PDF. Why would you use that as actual mode of transportation? A pdf file is not a files archive. Can't you just use a zip file or something, and generate the pdf on the side?